# Run related or same procedures in oracle database simultaneously to not interfering with each other

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have a software for creating especial reports that run procedures in oracle database but the problem is:
when we create a report it uses some procedures and truncate and fill some tables, if we create another report at the same time it caused an error because it needs my table information that are truncated with another procedure. So I am looking for a technique or query to handle this problem and create the second report just after the first report finishing all the procedures that it use in the state that user do not notice anything. In this case the time that the second report is going to be create is more than the first report that it is alright.

Comment: Are you using PL/SQL procedures?

Comment: yes, I am using PL/SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DBMS_LOCK.ALLOCATE_UNIQUE` package in order to synchronize your applications and enforcing sequential processing.

```
DECLARE
    l_status number;
    l_lock_handle varchar2(128);
    l_lock_request integer;
BEGIN
    DBMS_LOCK.ALLOCATE_UNIQUE ( lockname =>  'NAME_OF_YOUR_LOCK', lockhandle => l_lock_handle);
    l_status := DBMS_LOCK.REQUEST(lockhandle => l_lock_handle, timeout => 15);
    if (l_status = 0) then
      -- Plase your code here
      -- Only one thread can work here
      l_lock_request  := DBMS_LOCK.release(l_lock_handle);
    else
      -- handle other lock statuses...
    end if;
END;
```

You can read more about DBMS_LOCK [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_lock.htm#ARPLS66782).

Comment: Thank you very much in the code that you wrote, When I run another procedure the user do not face an error right? The user just must wait or in other word the second procedure go to a some kind of queue and automatically run when the first procedure finished?

Comment: It depends. In success scenario - yes. When other status will be returned (timeout, deadlock etc) then you have to handle it manually